# Crawling a field from URL and building a rank table

Tags: python, web-crawler

This is my first project in scrapping data from a website so please guide me because I am gonna sound like a newbie definitely. So here is what I want to do: scrap the field **Church Size** on the URL. The identifier here is the number **5611**. I want to build a table where it will rank the postings based upon Church Size (1st row shall be highest number and last line shall be lowest number) from identifier 5550 to 5615. Can anybody help with basic code snippet with which I can play around myself. Thanks a lot.

URL : https://oppsearch.ucc.org/web/fastdetails.aspx?id=5611&KeepThis=false&TB_iframe=true&height=&width=

EDIT1:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://oppsearch.ucc.org/web/fastdetails.aspx?id=4784&KeepThis=false&TB_iframe=true&height=798&width=960"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="ContentPlaceHolder1_city")
print(results.prettify())
```

Results into: (where Lowden is expected city, so this proves the trial code is working )

```
jatinkashyap@Jatins-Air UCC % python3 trial.py
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_city">
 Lowden
</span>
```

Comment: In general I would suggest `requests` plus `beautifulsoup4` for this kind of problem. Can you show the code you've tried so far?

Comment: @NickODell Just inserted the EDIT1 to share my trial code. I am doing it for the city name so far and I need to generalize this code to A) Insert three other element State, Size, Name and B) Run it through around 400 pages. I am thinking to put it into a For loop but I am afraid they can block my IP if I ping the server too much. Further any hint to build the table so I can rank the entries based upon Size? Thanks.